# Manifold and submanifold, in $S$ a submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have a theorem that says that:

**Theorem :** Let $M,N$ smooths manifolds and $f:M\to N$ a smooth application.

If $Rg(f)=k$ in a neighborhood of $S=f^{-1}(q), q\in N$ then $S$ is a submanifold of dimension $n-k$.

Then, I have a remark that says that if $Rg(f,x)=k$ for all $x\in S$, we can't conclude that $S$ is a smooth manifold. I recall that $Rg(f,x)=Rg(d_xf).$

**My question :** So if I understand well, if $Rg(f,x)=k$ for all $x\in S$, then we can't conclude that $S$ is a submanifold, but if there is an open $U\supset S$ s.t. $Rg(f,x)=k$ for all $x\in U$, then $S$ is a submanifold of dimension $n-k$. Did I understand well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For a simple example demonstrating this point, consider your favorite smooth bump function

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & |x| < 1, \\
                        0 & |x| \geq 1.
          \end{cases}
$$

Then $f^{-1}(0) = \{ x \, | \, |x| \geq 1 \}$ and for all $x \in f^{-1}(0)$ we have $f'(x) = 0$. So $df$ is of constant rank $0$ on $f^{-1}(0)$ but $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a $1 - 0 = 1$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is something I don't understand: I agree that the $Rg(f')=0$ on $S$, but why $f^{-1}$ is not a sub-manifold ? I don't see the trick here.

Comment: The set $f^{-1}(0)$ is just $(-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty)$ and is not a manifold because the points $\pm1$ don't have neighborhoods homeomorphic to an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. It is a manifold with boundary but this is not really relevant - you can also construct examples in which $f^{-1}(0)$ is a quite ugly closed set.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but I am a little bit lost. So it's a manifold with boundary, but it's not manifold ? Sorry but I don't understand. Could you give me more detail ? (I'm sorry, but I start this chapter). Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of a manifold?

Comment: $M$ is a manifold if it's Hausdorff, second countable and locally homeomorphic to $\overline{\mathbb H}^n=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid x_n\geq 0\}$ or locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: That's the usual definition of a manifold-with-boundary; a manifold is usually allowed to only be locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. So I can see why you were confused.

Comment: You can consider then $g(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$. Then $g^{-1}(0)$ won't be a manifold with boundary (it will be something that's called manifold with corners but it won't be a manifold according to your definition) and $dg$ still has constant rank $0$ on $g^{-1}(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

That's right: just because $f$ restricted to $S$ has rank $k$ everywhere is not enough; you need for $f$ to have rank $k$ everywhere *near* $S$ as well.

Note that in this theorem, the manifold $N$ can be replaced by $\mathbb R^n$, since only a single point of $N$ (or a neighborhood of that point) ends up mattering.

That might help you construct an example where this subtle difference (constant rank *on* $S$ vs *near* $S$) matters, something I cannot do off the top of my head.